# MySQL: Cumulate values based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below. I need to cumulate values for each user, but stop cumulating when there is a break in the month.

Input:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id | month       | period         |
+----+-------------+----------------+
| A  | 2015-09-01  |              0 |
| A  | 2015-10-01  |              1 |
| A  | 2015-11-01  |             15 |
| A  | 2016-04-01  |              2 |
| A  | 2016-05-01  |              0 |
| B  | 2015-09-01  |              0 |
| B  | 2015-10-01  |              1 |
| B  | 2015-12-01  |             15 |
| B  | 2016-01-01  |              2 |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| id | month       | period         | result column         |
+----+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| A  | 2015-09-01  |              0 |                     0 |
| A  | 2015-10-01  |              1 |                     1 |
| A  | 2015-11-01  |             15 |                    16 |
| A  | 2016-04-01  |              2 |                     2 |
| A  | 2016-05-01  |              0 |                     2 |
| B  | 2015-09-01  |              0 |                     0 |
| B  | 2015-10-01  |              1 |                     1 |
| B  | 2015-12-01  |             15 |                    15 |
| B  | 2016-01-01  |              2 |                    17 |
+----+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Input:

+----+-------------+----------------+ 
| id | month | period | 
+----+-------------+----------------+ 
| A | 2015-09-01 | 0 | 
| A | 2015-10-01 | 1 | 
| A | 2015-11-01 | 15 | 
| A | 2016-04-01 | 2 | 
| A | 2016-05-01 | 0 | 
| B | 2015-09-01 | 0 | 
| B | 2015-10-01 | 1 | 
| B | 2015-12-01 | 15 | 
| B | 2016-01-01 | 2 | 
+----+-------------+----------------+

Comment: There's no question in your question.

Comment: I want to write a query to get the output i have posted

Comment: Yeah, okay, do so. Come back when you have problems and can describe them.

Comment: I tried to write this query, but it cumulated all the values for the id irrespective of the month:
select a.id, a.month, a.period, sum(b.period) from table a join table b on a.id=b.id and b.month <= a.month group by 1,2;

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev_id = id 
         THEN CASE WHEN @prev_month = month - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
           THEN @i := @i+period ELSE @i := period END 
          ELSE @i := 0 END i
     , @prev_id := id
     , @prev_month := month 
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev_id:=null,@prev_month:=null,@i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY id
     , month;
```

...or something like that